# Newbie question about Powershell DSC and nodes

Tags: powershell, dsc

For a school project I got interested in Windows DSC but I get stuck on something stupid and I can't find the answer anywhere, it must be obvious but yet for me it is not. I'm just starting out, so I created a silly script to install telnet based on a youtube video I saw:

```
Demo Configuration {

Node localhost {

WINDOWSFEATURE Telnet {

ENSURE = 'PRESENT'

NAME = 'Telnet-Client'

}

}

}

Demo
```

Well until then everything is fine, I created the affiliate mof, I run the script and tadam it works. The problem is that I mainly want to use this script on a machine on the same network (let's say I'm 10.1.0.1 and she is 10.1.0.2). We ping each other, everything is fine. All the tutorials talk about Node, so that's nice, I wrote Node localhost, 10.1.0.2 or even Node 10.1.0.2, but if I do that, the connection is refused since I do not give any identifier or password. How am I supposed to configure these remote nodes exactly?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Node localhost or the hostname of the target server, then this ought to work:

```
$credential = Get-Credential
Start-DscConfiguration -Path .\mofFolder\ -ComputerName 10.1.0.2 -Credential $credential -Wait -Verbose
```

Otherwise, try copying example 3 from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psdesiredstateconfiguration/start-dscconfiguration?view=powershell-5.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.1)